# How to create a good modular project structure in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I spent quite a lot of time thinking about how should I organize a good modular structure for my Qt C++ project. Unfortunately, I did not find a complete example on how to do it right (am I missing something?), so I am looking for an advice. So far, I came with the following assumptions:

- I would like to have separate directory for modules, because each of them may be used in sevaral apps.
- I would like to have unit tests for each module.
- I also thought that keepng tests right inside module's folder is a good decision, because if I want to move or rename a module, nothing will be broken, because I can use relative paths to the module's sources in my tests.

So my desired project structure looks like this:

```
|project_root
    |src
        src.pro (TEMPLATE = subdirs)
        |apps
            apps.pro (TEMPLATE = subdirs)
            |my_app
                my_app.pro (TEMPLATE = app)
                main.cpp
                ...
        |modules
            modules.pro (TEMPLATE = subdirs)
            |my_module
                my_module.pro (TEMPLATE = ???)
                |tests
                    tests.pro (TEMPLATE = subdirs)
                    |MyClass1Test
                        MyClass1Test.pro (TEMPLATE = app)
                        tst_myclass1test.cpp
                    |MyClass2Test
                        MyClass2Test.pro (TEMPLATE = app)
                        tst_myclass2test.cpp
                MyClass1.h
                MyClass1.cpp
                MyClass2.h
                MyClass2.cpp
```

My first question is - is this structure good in context of Qt Creator's logic? Am I doing something completely wrong?

My second question is about implementation of my_module.pro. Which template should I use here? I was playing around four types of project templates: *subdirs, lib, aux*, and I could not manage to organize my module structure as above (that's why I am looking for a logical error). There are some reasons for that:

- If I use `TEMPLATE = subdirs` for my_module.pro, Qt Creator does not recognize any files inside it (MyClass1.h, MyClass1.cpp, ... disapper from project structure) and I can't build a library any more
- If I use a `TEMPLATE = lib` or `TEMPLATE = aux`, then I'm unable to create *tests* subproject in this folder

So my third question is: How should I organize my project in a good way to overcome these issues?

Comment: Not sure if this is good for stack overflow, I'd probably ask it on Programmers. Nevertheless, good questions. I'd surely too make use of some answers.

Comment: Thanks for an advice, Tomas! If I don't get an answer here for some time, I'll post the question on Programmers too.

Comment: Qmake's pro files unfortunately only work for a single template type. That means you'll need to move `MyClass.h` etc into a subdirectory and have the `my_module.pro` use a `subdirs` template. This would build both tests and the actual source for the module.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: I have recently answered somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514620/qt-creator-how-to-run-subdirs-projects/41515424#41515424 In regards to most of what you ask for: provide correct dependencies and not go deep through that tree. And one more thing: symbolic links e.g. `ln -s sourceDir destDir` also help in case if it is too hard to maintain within same file system directory structure.

Comment: AlexanderVX gave me a good food for thought. I realized that it is not possible to keep tests in module's directory without using additional `src` subfolder. But I also found an interesting AutoTest plugin for Qt and it seems to be a good soultion. It allows to keep the whole test suite separate from the modules and to run many tests at once.