# Creating subprojects using qtCreator ide?

Tags: c++, qt, code-structure

I am currently working on a project which would involve generating a few components. To make life easier I want to seperate each component, such that they can be compiled independently, and tested indenpendently, and merge them together to a top-level project, when all the components need to be used to together.   I am using qt as IDE, which doesn't seem to have a native way to split the cmakelist, such that a subproject and can exist within a top-project, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're looking for, but QtCreator has no problem recognizing subfolders with their own cmakelists that are added to the main list.

Comment: With qmake (not cmake) it is easy to do: https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514620/qt-creator-how-to-run-subdirs-projects

Comment: As @AlexanderVX said, qmake can easily handle the subdirectory, i.e. subproject, inclusion of cmake projects.

Check his link and create a qmake wrapper around your cmake components.

Otherwise you could create a wrapper Cmake that adds Libraries and Executables... Maybe the Qt IDE recognizes these as subprojects. I'm not sure on this, though. 

EDIT: https://www.reddit.com/r/Qt5/comments/5kjfyp/qt_creator_project_with_subprojects_using_qbs_or/ 

Seems to be straightforward. :D

Comment: or just with qmake for all projects...

Comment: I am looking for a way in which i can structure a big project in to a set of module of smaller project, which combined into a big project.